# Is flask instantiate required in each module of the app?

Tags: python, flask

Hi I'm a Django developer and recently have started working on an existing flask app of the organization. I found the coder of the app has added a following line in each module/file of the app.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

From this line, I understood that, it instantiates the flask app. But if so, why that line is added in each module. He has used the variable `app` multiple times. But I doubt, this line should be at once only and later it should be `imported`.

So, the query is :
Is the flask instantiate required in each module of the app?

Note - The earlier coder has left the organisation and nobody is familiar with flask in my org.

Comment: Not used Flask much but that doesn't sound right at all. That would couple every single module with Flask including any that you didn't write.

Comment: It must be incorrect. See http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/ for how you are supposed to be doing it

Comment: @Fiskie - Thanks for the doc link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the developer is misunderstanding how Flask works. You create **one** `Flask()` instance and import that in every module of the project that needs to have access to it.